# How to create a flow generator for a given iterable object?

Tags: python

Write a function that produces stream generator for given iterable object (list, generator, etc) whose elements contain position and value and sorted by order of apperance. Stream generator should be equal to initial stream (without position) but gaps filled with zeroes. For example:

`gen = gen_stream(9,[(4,111),(7,12)])`

`list(gen) [0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]` # first element has zero index, so 111 located on fifth position, 12 located on 8th position
I.e. 2 significant elements has indexes 4 and 7, all other elements filled with zeroes.

To simplify things elements are sorted (i.e element with lower position should precede element with higher number) in initial stream.

First parameter can be None, in this case stream should be inifinite, e.g. infinite zeroes stream:
`gen_stream(None, [])`

following stream starts with 0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, ... then infinitely generates zeroes:

`gen_stream(None, [(4,111),(7,12)])`

Function should also support custom position-value extractor for more advanced cases, e.g.

```
def day_extractor(x):
  months = [31,28,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,30,31]
  acc = sum(months[:x[1]-1]) + x[0] - 1
  return (acc, x[2])
    precipitation_days = [(3,1,4),(5,2,6)]
    list(gen_stream(59,precipitation_days,day_extractor)) #59: January and February to limit output
[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

precipitation_days format is following: (d,m,mm), where d - day in month, m - month, mm - precipitation in millimeters
So, in example:
(3,1,4) - January,3 precipitation: 4 mm
(5,2,6) - February,5 precipitation: 6 mm
Extractor passed as optional third parameter with default value - lambda function that handles (position, value) pairs like in first example.

That's what i did:

```
    import sys
    a=[(4,111),(7,12)]
    n = 9
    def gen_stream(n1, a1):
     if n1==None:
      b = [0 for i in range(sys.maxsize)]
     else:
      b = [0 for i in range(n1)]
     for i in range(len(a1)):
         b[a[i][0]]=a[i][1]
     for i in range(len(b)):
       yield b[i]
    for i in gen_stream(None, a):
        print(i)
```

So far I have reached a stream with infinite zeros, but the function is not executed for some reason ... And how to do it next with months? My memory error crashes, and the program eats a lot of RAM (((help please